# H2O frame-based prediction using Java POJO/MOJO and EasyPredictModelWrapper

Tags: h2o

I've trained a linear model in R and exported a POJO which I've embedded in a (Java) SpringBoot webapp. Wrapping the POJO using the `EasyPredictModelWrapper` and instantiating an object is well described in the tutorials:

```
hex.genmodel.GenModel rawModel = (hex.genmodel.GenModel) Class.forName(modelClassName).newInstance();
model = new EasyPredictModelWrapper(rawModel);
```

I can assemble a `RowData` object:

```
RowData row = new RowData();
row.put("feature1", this.feature1);
```

and obtain a prediction for that row:

```
BinomialModelPrediction p = model.predictBinomial(row);
```

I've also exported the same model as a MOJO - the deployment procedure is almost identical.

My use case is that I receive a variable-length list of objects which need scoring, so I iterate the list and construct a row for each object, pass that to the wrapper and receive the prediction. So far so good.

Now I want to use a more sophisticated model that considers all the rows simultaneously. In R it's a case of passing a dataframe to the model, rather than a row (and receiving a dataframe back).

My question is: how can I pass a dataframe to a generated model object? I've gone over the source in [the h2o-3 repo](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/tree/master/h2o-genmodel/src/main/java/hex/genmodel), read the title of every SO post in the `h2o` tag and scrolled through the [JIRA board](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/projects/PUBDEV/issues/PUBDEV-5522?filter=allissues) until I got RSI, and the closest thing I've found is a DriverlessAI class called [MojoFrame](http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/python-mojo-pipelines.html#compile-and-run-the-mojo-from-java), though the example given is a transform rather than a prediction.

I'm fairly sure that the `EasyPredictModelWrapper` doesn't support multirow input - the source is all about the `RowData` class. It would be great if it does but it's not necessarily a showstopper.

I'm less sure about the underlying model implementation: the `MojoFrame` and `FrameBuilder` classes tend to imply that it's supported within DriverlessAI, which may or may not use the same MOJO. Also the `H2OFrame` class crops up now and then in the context of scoring from Spark/R/Python, so although that's for a native model rather than the generated Java object it gives me hope that the model format can support it, and that a possible route might be to extend the support classes.

Options I've considered but haven't tested yet:

- modify `EasyPredictModelWrapper` to accept Frames (lots of effort to understand the MOJO format)
- renormalise the input list into a single row (breaks the frame-based paradigm for training the model, which probably breaks the whole process)

Has anyone done multi-row / frame-based input with the generated POJO or MOJO artifacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H2O-3 MOJO/POJOs are row-based.  The EasyPredictModelWrapper is a convenient wrapper for making row-based predictions.

If you want to make more than one prediction, then using a for-loop is a fine answer.

Even if sometime in the future the API expands to accept some kind of frame, it won't do anything different than the for-loop would.

(Note that this should not be confused with Driverless AI MOJOs, which are not interchangeable and do have some different properties.)

---

> I'm less sure about the underlying model implementation: the MojoFrame and FrameBuilder classes tend to imply that it's supported within DriverlessAI, which may or may not use the same MOJO.

Despite sharing a common name of MOJO, H2O-3 MOJOs and Driverless AI MOJOs are different implementations and not interchangeable.

MOJO-ness qualities that they share are:

- the resulting artifact doesn't need to be compiled (unlike the H2O-3 POJO, which is Java code)
- a java runtime is supported
- low latency, so suited for real-time applications
- works efficiently on one row at a time, so suited for streaming applications

Driverless AI MOJOs include feature engineering transformations as well as a predictive model.

---

> My question is: how can I pass a dataframe to a generated model object? I've gone over the source in the h2o-3 repo

You can't with the current H2O-3 MOJO API.  The H2O-3 MOJO API is a row-based API.  One could, of course, extend the API to do some kind of for-loop approach.

---

> Now I want to use a more sophisticated model that considers all the rows simultaneously

I don't know what "considers all the rows simultaneously" means.  This isn't what the H2O-3 MOJO API or EasyPredictModelWrapper do.  The underlying math is row-by-row.  Even if you put a convenience function around the math to take a frame of values, it would still calculate the results row-by-row, with the individual rows calculated one-by-one in isolation in a theoretically embarrassingly parallel way using a simple for loop, or some other fancy way if you needed parallelism for speed.

In the H2O-3 MOJO API, the result calculated for row N has no impact on the result calculated for rows N-1 or N+1 (or, more generally, the result for any row other than N).

(Note that for Driverless AI MOJOs, since feature engineering is incorporated, it is possible the above row-by-row discussion may be different.  A good example is time-series windowing calculations.  Such a discussion is beyond the scope of this question and answer, but worth pointing out in this context.)